# What is the earliest manuscript of the Gloria in excelsis Deo (Greater Doxology) hymn?

Tags: catholicism, early-church, hymns

What is the earliest manuscript of the *Gloria in excelsis Deo* (Greater [Doxology](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05150a.htm)) hymn?

Answer (score 3):

According to Adrian Fortescue's [*The Mass: A Study in the Roman Liturgy*](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/2857), "§6. Gloria in Excelsis", [p. 238](https://archive.org/stream/cu31924029398553#page/n255/mode/2up), the *Gloria in excelsis*

> is found first [in Greek] in St. Athanasius' treatise: *de Virginitate* [*sive de ascesi*]<sup>1</sup> as part of morning prayer (with [Ps. lxii](http://drbo.org/drl/chapter/21062.htm), and the Benedicite) and in the [Greek Old and New Testament manuscript, the] [Codex alexandrinus](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/04080c.htm) (V<sup>th</sup> cent.).<sup>2</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>1. C. 20 ([P.G. xxviii](https://patristica.net/graeca/#t028), [275](https://archive.org/details/patrologiaecurs130migngoog/page/n148/mode/2up)). The authenticity of this work, long disputed, now seems more generally admitted. See Eichhorn: [*Athanasii de vita ascetica testimonia*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7163) (Halle, 1886) p[p. 27](https://books.google.com/books?id=UI9v4fQ5vmMC&pg=PA27) seq., and especially von der Goltz in *Texte und Untersuchungen*, N.S. xiv, 2 *a*.
> 2. As an appendix to the psalms at the end.</sup>

<sup>cf. also "[Psalter](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/12543b.htm)" and [my answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/54746/1787) to the question "How did the Catholic Church function logistically/liturgically prior to the invention of the printing press?"</sup>